# Lead assignment rules not working on Web-to-Lead form

Tags: assignment-rules, web2lead

I'm trying to test a simple lead assignment rule in order to start routing leads to different regional sales teams. I created a Web-to-Lead form and used the following default assignment rule criteria to test if it's working:

Lead: Country equals US,USA,United States,United States of America

From what I can tell, it's defaulting to the Default Lead Owner under Lead Settings. What am I missing to fix this so it actually uses the rule to assign to the appropriate queue?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. The way you are checking Lead:Country is incorrect
2. Do this, the way i have added it in the image
   [image]

Comment: Yes, thank you! I needed to switch over to CONTAINS. The Standard default rule that SFDC drops into a new developer org also seems to be buggy. I copied everything over to a new rule and it started working.